# Assigning a chrome developer tools profiles heap string to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome-devtools

[image: Snapshot]

I am not able to select the string "They were often....." directly on the webpage or in HTML because it is used under canvas.

I created a memory heap of page and found the string.

Is there any way by which i can assign this string to a variable? like:

```
var foo = document.fa.fn.init[1].content;
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want here but if you just want to have the text in your clipboard, just double tap on the value part of the `content` property and it will select it, then just Cmd + C / Ctrl + C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Store as Global Variable" option from the context menu. It will make the value accessible in the console as `temp1`.

[image]

Comment: Oddly enough I was looking for "Store as Global Variable" earlier but it didn't show up for me. Re-opened the browser and it's showing now.

Comment: Creating snapshot takes time. is not there a way by which i can assign that value to a variable without creating heapshot?